# Dynamically Hide/Unhide Multiple Ranges Using VBA With Minimal Lag

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to dynamically hide or unhide rows in a worksheet based off of selections within dropdown menus.

The script that I have works with smaller data sets, but because I have 35 different ranges of 26 rows each this slows down really quickly.

I have seen several solutions offered to similar question here, but I have been unable to get them to work.

I want to collect the value in cells B15 down to B41 and hide any rows that have a blank value, then repeat for the remaining 34 ranges.

Each of the cells in the range above have a formula that can return a "" value (which are the rows I want to hide).

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   'Turns off worksheet protection to allow for hiding and unhiding of rows
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "xxxx"
   
   'Turns off screen updating and animations while hiding and unhiding rows
    Application.EnableAnimations = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      
    Hide1
    Hide2
    Hide3
    Hide4
    Hide5
    Hide6
    Hide7
    Hide8
    Hide9
    Hide10
    Hide11
    Hide12
    Hide13
    Hide14
    Hide15

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableAnimations = True
    
    ActiveSheet.Protect "xxxx"
    
End Sub

Sub Hide1()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.EnableAnimations = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Run #1

    If Range("B15").Value = "" Then
        Rows(15).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(15).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B16").Value = "" Then
        Rows(16).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(16).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B17").Value = "" Then
        Rows(17).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(17).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B18").Value = "" Then
        Rows(18).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(18).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B19").Value = "" Then
        Rows(19).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(19).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B20").Value = "" Then
        Rows(20).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(20).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B21").Value = "" Then
        Rows(21).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(21).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B22").Value = "" Then
        Rows(22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B23").Value = "" Then
        Rows(23).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(23).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B24").Value = "" Then
        Rows(24).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(24).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B25").Value = "" Then
        Rows(25).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(25).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B26").Value = "" Then
        Rows(26).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(26).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B27").Value = "" Then
        Rows(27).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(27).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B28").Value = "" Then
        Rows(28).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(28).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B29").Value = "" Then
        Rows(29).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(29).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B30").Value = "" Then
        Rows(30).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(30).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("B31").Value = "" Then
        Rows(31).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows(31).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.EnableAnimations = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you want hiding all the rows where a formula return empty in B:B column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next code. As it is set, it will hide all rows having empty values returned by a formula. `firstR`and `lastR` can be chosen to process a specific number of rows:

```
Sub Hide1()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, firstR As Long
 Dim rng As Range, rngH As Range, arr, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on B:B
 firstR = 15          'first row of the range to be processed
 Set rng = sh.Range("B" & firstR & ":B" & lastR)
 rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False       'show all rows in the range

 arr = rng.Value                    'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = "" Then
        If rngH Is Nothing Then    'set the range to keep the cells where the rows must be hidden
            Set rngH = rng.cells(i, 1)
        Else
           Set rngH = Union(rngH, rng.cells(i, 1))
        End If
    End If
 Next
 'hide the rows at once:
 If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This works nearly perfectly, but seems to not want to keep working after getting to about the 10th range set. The rows stop hiding and unhiding automatically. Do the variable declarations need to change for each range set?

Comment: @Patrick Cushing Do you use the code **as it is**, only changing the first and last row? It should work on any interval. I cannot imagine what was your 'contribution' in improving it... Can you edit your question and paste the code you use? What do you mean by **each range set**? No need to change the variables in any circumstance.

Comment: What I mean by each range set is this:  First section is B15:B31, second section is B37:B52, third section is b58:b73, ... all the way out to 35 sections.

Comment: @Patrick Cushing So, not the interval is the problem. I am afraid you modified something and if I am not able to see your code, I cannot say anything about a solution. Can you share the workbook you use? Of course deleting sensitive data, if the case...

Comment: The only line I changed was the following:  lastR = 31 'last row on B:B from your lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on B:B.  I can absolutely share the workbook, what is the preferred method here?

Comment: @Patrick Cushing This cannot be true! I offered myself to check your workbook, see what code you use, in which circumstances. I also looked to your **new** question and I cannot understand too much. What do you mean by "**selection changes are made from the drop downs and column B updates**"? Did you place the code in an event? Do you think that you can change the question according to any new needs? In our community this way of acting is not allowed. Even in these circumstances I can help **only if I am able to understand what you do and want doing**.

Comment: @Patrick Cushing it is not a "preferred method". Usually it is not recommended. It is accepted if OP cannot explain in detail the circumstances of a solution which **worked** and now **does not work**, anymore. Of course, if we have availability for such a gesture... You can use a transfer site or send it on my personal mail (from my profile). But, separate of this aspect, please revert your last edit to the initial question! Then edit it and add the new request, but with all circumstances details.

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Blank Rows

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideBlankRows()
    
    Const fCellAddress As String = "B16"
    Const crgCount As Long = 35
    Const crgSize As Long = 16 ' maybe 26 ?
    Const crgGap As Long = 5
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Range(fCellAddress).Resize(crgSize)
    Dim crgOffset As Long: crgOffset = crgSize + crgGap
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = crg
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 2 To crgCount
        Set crg = crg.Offset(crgOffset)
        Set rg = Union(rg, crg)
    Next n
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim cCell As Range
    
    For Each cCell In rg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(cCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            If drg Is Nothing Then
                Set drg = cCell
            Else
                Set drg = Union(drg, cCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cCell
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 
    rg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    drg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
End Sub
```